# Why isnt my regex for DOB being accepted?

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I am working on a schema, and want to make the following restrictions DOB Between 01/01/1970 and 12/31/2000 inclusive.

My code below is:

```
xs:element name="DOB">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="([0][1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(199[0-9]|200[0-9]|201[01])"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

I am getting this validation error:

> ERROR: Element 'DOB': [facet 'pattern'] The value '2/3/1981' is not accepted by the pattern '([0][1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(199[0-9]|200[0-9]|201[01])'.

Answer (score 3):

Try making the first digit of the day and month optional, should that day or month be 1-9:

```
<xs:pattern value="(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(19[7-9][0-9]|2000)"/>
```

### Demo

Beyond this, your pattern for catching the years also had a problem.  I use the following pattern to match all years from 1/1/1970 to 12/31/2000:

```
(19[7-9][0-9]|2000)
```

Comment: This answers OP's specific question (+1), but I'd like to recommend that OP and subsequent readers use ISO-8601-based [`xsd:date`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#date) where possible for improved interoperability.   Michael Kay [provides a helpful example of adding date restrictions to `xs:date` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5211567/290085).